# How to copy contents of a textbox to another textbox using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have two text boxes `t1` and `t2` in an html page.

I'd like to copy `t1` content to `t2`, using javascript on every keystroke done in `t1`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ol' school, since you added the "beginner" tag:

```
<input type="text" id="t1" onkeyup="document.getElementById('t2').value = this.value" />
<input type="text" id="t2" />
```

A more robust solution also uses the `change` event (for those who paste via mouse right-click), and doesn't inline the event handler logic:

```
<input type="text" id="t1" />
<input type="text" id="t2" />

<script>
var t1 = document.getElementById('t1');
t1.onkeyup = t1.onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById('t2').value = this.value;
};
</script>
```

Comment: this is not unobtrusive. you should teach beginner to have good manners when coding html/js .)

Answer (score 3):

Using jquery this would look something like this:

`$(function() { $(t1).keyup(function() { $(t2).val($(t1).val()) } })`

Comment: where to write  what is the syntax we need to use here

Comment: <head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  ...the code...
  </script>
</head>

Comment: actually it doesn't matter since the function will be hooked to keyup event after dom is ready.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this ugly thing:

```
<html>
<body>
  <textarea id="t1" onkeyup="document.getElementById("t2").value = this.value;"></textarea>
  <textarea id="t2"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```